How to determine the confidence intervals for the principal axes of a second-rank tensor?
The question in short: How does one estimate the confidence intervals for the principal axes of a second-rank symmetric tensor when the measurement errors are themselves a function of the values of the principal axes?
Here I describe the question abstractly, mathematically, and then further below I provide a numerical example.
The abstract description: The tensor considered is a linear relationship between certain pairs of physical vector quantities which may be described by 3 x 3 symmetric matrix. From measurements at a given point in the physical medium, the least squares estimate of the components of the tensor at that point are obtained; from these the tensor's principal axes (magnitudes and directions) may be estimated. However, the error in the measurements is a function of the magnitude of the principal values of the tensor, their orientation with respect to the direction of the measurement, and the dimensions of the sample being measured.
The mathematical description: The true scalar magnitude $k$ of the second-rank symmetric tensor $k_{ij}$ in a specific direction defined by the unit vector $u_i$ is
$$\tag{1} k=k_{ij}u_i u_j \ \ (i,j=1,2,3).$$
However, in practice due to the physical boundary conditions required to perform the measurement, the measured value of $k$ in this direction is a function of $k_{ij}, u_i, D/L$. The relationship for this measured apparent value is
$$\tag{2} k_a = \sqrt{\frac{k_{ij}u_iu_j}{r_{kl}u_ku_l}}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{k_{ij}u_iu_jr_{kl}u_ku_l}(D/L)^2}{\sqrt{k_{ij}u_iu_jr_{kl}u_ku_l}+(D/L)^2}\right],$$
where $r_{kl}$ is the matrix inverse of $k_{ij}$, i.e., $r_{ij}=k_{ij}^{-1}$. Thus, there is an error when making the measurement on a finite-dimensioned sample of diameter $D$ and length $L$. (error $=k-k_a$).
To retrieve the six coefficients of the tensor $k_{ij}$, one needs six or more measurements in independent directions. The parameter vector $\textbf{K}$ containing the six coefficients of the tensor $k_{ij}$ can be classically obtained by computing the least-squares calculation:
$$\tag{3} \bf{K}=(\bf{\Theta}^t \bf{\Theta})^{-1} \bf{\Theta}^t \bf{M},$$
where $\bf{\Theta}$ is the design matrix built from the second order products of the components of the unit vector that defines the specific direction of the measurement. If the unit vector is $u_i=(u_1, u_2, u_3)$, then, the corresponding row of the design matrix $\bf{\Theta}$ is $(u_1^2, u_2^2, u_3^2, 2u_2u_3, 2u_3u_1, 2u_1u_2)$. $\bf{M}$ is the measurement vector (whose components are the six or more $k_a$ measurements).
Once the six coefficients are retrieved, the eigenvalue problem may be solved to obtain the orientation of the three principal axes and the principal values.
A numerical example: We want to determine the values of $k_{ij}$ of a physical sample. Since nothing is known beforehand about the orientation of the principal axes of $k_{ij}$, arbitrary axes $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are chosen, and six (sub)-samples are cut at various orientations for "directional" measurements of $k$. Six measurements were made along the following directions defined by the unit vector $u_i$ with the components $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$:

Suppose the following measured values were:

I note for you here that these values were derived from Eqn(2), where I have selected the true values for $k_{ij}$ -- the values we are trying to solve for in this hypothetical exercise. In the real-world scenario, we would only have the values of our measurements, our $k_a$ values, and we can only try our best to determine what the true $k_{ij}$ values are.
The samples all had a $D/L$ ratio of $2$.
Using the above $u_i$ and $k_a$ values in Eqn(3) we can solve for the $k_{ij}$, the values of which are shown below in the 3x3 symmetric matrix:
$k_{ij}=$
We now solve the eigenvalue problem to obtain the orientation of the three principal axes and the principal values, which are as follows:

Focusing on the principal values, 14.29, 1.29, and 0.92, how can we estimate the confidence intervals on these values?

The description is quite long, so I may have missed something. So you have a tensor $\mathbf{k}=k^{ij}\mathbf{e_i}\otimes \mathbf{e_j}$, $k^{ij}=k^{ji}$. You then are interested in the projection of this tensor along some vector $\mathbf{u}$, to get a quantity:
$$
k=k^{ij}\left(\mathbf{e}_i.\mathbf{u}\right)\left(\mathbf{e}_j.\mathbf{u}\right)
$$
To estimate uncertainty it might be a good idea to model how this uncertainty arises. Is there uncertainty in the values of $k^{ij}$ (e.g. thermal fluctuations), or are there uncertainties in which vector you actually end up projecting along ($\mathbf{u}$). Lets say the latter. What is the type of uncertainty you have in $\mathbf{u}$? You are using OLS, which often goes together with normal distribution, so lets assume:
$$
\mathbf{u}\sim Normal\left(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)
$$
NB! this assumption means that $\mathbf{u}$ need not be normalized! For normalized $\mathbf{u}$ you will need to consider a different distribution (for example distribution on a surface of a unit sphere to which your $\mathbf{u}$ points).
With this you can express:
$$
k=u_i\,k_{ij} u_j
$$
If your matrix $k_{ij}$ is positive semi-definite so that it can be represented as $k_{ij}=\sum_sa_{is}a_{js}$ for some matrix $a_{is}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix), then $k$ will be a sum of squares of normally distributed variables: $k=v_i v_i,\,v_i=a_{is}u_s$, and you should be able to tackle it with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution.
If $k_{ij}$ is not positive semi-definite, it can still be diagonalized, since it is symmetric, and then your should be able to write it as $k_{ij}=k^{(p)}_{ij}-k^{(m)}_{ij}$, where $k^{(p,m)}_{ij}$ are both positive semi-definite, so:
$$
\begin{align}
k&=u_ik^{(p)}_{ij}u_j-u_ik^{(m)}_{ij}u_j=u_ia_{is}a_{js}u_j-u_i b_{is}b_{js}u_j=\sum_iv_i^2-\sum_j w_j^2=v^2-w^2 \\
v_i&\sim Normal\left(\mathbf{a} \boldsymbol{\mu},\, \mathbf{a}^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{a}\right) \\
w_i&\sim Normal\left(\mathbf{b} \boldsymbol{\mu},\, \mathbf{b}^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{b}\right)
\end{align}
$$
So the value $k$ will be given by the difference of two non-central chi-squared variables.If you are primarily interested in $k$ you don't need to work out $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ etc - you simply need to fit parameters of $v^2$ and $w^2$ from the data. Can be done on maximum likelihood probably. This, in turn, will give you the distribution of $k$, including the interval.
For more complex distributions of $\mathbf{u}$, the process will probably be the same, but you will not have non-central chi-squared distribution. Maximum likelihood, coupled with some numerical scheme to handle integration (since you are going down from several random variables $\mathbf{u}$ to single $k$) will still work.
